# How to test Windows Phone 8.1 push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I'm searching google for something to test push notifications to Windows Phone 8.1, either an outline of what's required to make one or a pre-built test application.

Most of the results I'm finding relate to Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

As this is only for test, the unauthenticated service would more than suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These appear to be the answer:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Action-Center-Quickstart-b15089f2

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603

To add to this, you can test sending the Notifications to the phone using the emulator,

e.g. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBGNG.png <-- higher res image)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something that helped me was putting:

```
await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

just before:

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = backgroundTaskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(WindowsRuntimeComponent1.MyTask).FullName;
builder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());
builder.Register();
```

Now, open the 'tools' dialog from your emulator and select the 'Notifications' tab. Check the 'simulator' box.

IMPORTANT: Uninstall the app from the emulator then re-run it from visual studio. Once the app runs you should see your AppId and URI(if you don't then click the 'Refresh' button) in the 'Tools' dialog. You should now be able to set what type of notification you want and the payload text. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have account details mange push noficaion via [web](http://pushtestserver.azurewebsites.net/wns/)